# No Textview occurs in TableLayout

Tags: android

No Textview occurs in this TableLayout.  I don't know why.

I want to make the entries manually.

Another question, how can I add a horizontal line?

Code:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.overview);
        loadData();
        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tl);
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
        //tv.se
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        tv2.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        tv.setText("Test");
        tv2.setText("Test ");
        tv.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        tv2.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        //tv.setTextSize(50);
        //tv2.setTextSize(50);
        tr.addView(tv);
        tr.addView(tv2);
        tl.addView(tr);
        setContentView(tl);
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/tl">
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: why not just add the textview and table rows in the XML file?

Comment: the datasource is a sqlite db. its dynamic

Comment: by data source do you mean what is displayed in the text view?

Comment: no the count of TextViews is dynamic

Comment: Does logcat show any errors/exceptions

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you aren't setting any `LayoutParams` for your `TableRow`.

Try doing something like this:

```
tr.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Also if you want to add a horizontal line you can simply add a new `View` object and set its `layout_height` to `1dp` and its `backgroundColor` to `Color.BLACK`, or whatever height/color combination you want

Comment: what doesn't work? you need to be more descriptive in your responses

Comment: i only see a black screen no textview with hello in the left and the right.

Answer (score 0):

setContentView(R.layout.main);

```
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tl);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    //tv.se
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    tv2.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    tv.setText("Test");
    tv2.setText("Test ");
    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 //   tv2.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    //tv.setTextSize(50);
    //tv2.setTextSize(50);
    tr.addView(tv);
    tr.addView(tv2);
    tl.addView(tr);
```

main.xml

```
<TableLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/tl">
</TableLayout>
```

add new  horizontal line using

Comment: Hi use this 
 <TableLayout 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:stretchColumns="*"
  android:id="@+id/tl">
 </TableLayout>